# Transform string to timecode pattern?

Tags: javascript, timecodes

How can I get zeroes into my strings with the following results (a few examples):

- `1 => 01`
- `01.0 => 01.00`
- `1.0.01.00 => 01.00.01.00`
- `1.0.0.0 => 01:00:00:00`
- `10.0.10.0 => 10:00:10:00`

This is what I've come up with so far but it doesn't give me what I want. 
Thanks for help!

```
tc = tc.replace('.', ':');
tc = tc.replace(',', ':');
tc = tc.replace(/(:|^)(\d)(?=:|$)/g, "$10$2");
```

Comment: How about parsing the input into an object and then formatting the result?

Comment: @SeaBass Assuming you meant to use `:` in your first three examples of desired behavior, I have an answer for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend `0` to all single digits surrounded by word boundaries (`\b`), and then replace every comma and period with a colon using the character set `[.,]`. Don't forget to use the global (`g`) flag on each regular expression so that *every* occurrence of the target pattern is replaced, not just the first one.

```js
function timecode (s) {
  return s.replace(/\b(\d)\b/g, '0$1').replace(/[.,]/g, ':')
}

console.log(timecode('1') === '01')
console.log(timecode('01.0') === '01:00')
console.log(timecode('1.0.01.00') === '01:00:01:00')
console.log(timecode('1.0.0.0') === '01:00:00:00')
console.log(timecode('10.0.10.0') === '10:00:10:00')
```